# Инициализация рекурсивной структуры в С

Tags: c, esp32

Как можно выполнить, на этапе компиляции, инициализацию рекурсивной структуры?
Вот пример кода

```
struct menu_item {
    char name_menu[20];
    int level_menu;
    bool visible;
    struct menu_item *sub_menu[];
};

struct menu_item main_menu[] = { {"First item", 0, true, {}},
                               {"Second item", 0, true, {}},
                               {"The third item", 0, true, { {"First sub item", 0, true, {}},
                                                           {"Second sub item", 0, true, {}},
                                                           {"The third sub item", 0, true, {}},
                                                           {"Fourth sub item", 0, true, {}}
                                                         }},
                               {"Fourth item", 0, true, {}}
                              };
```

Вот так не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если поправить тип поля `sub_menu`, то можно создать нужную вам структуру. Ещё надо будет добавить `n_sub_menus` - указатели не хранят размер массива, на который ссылаются:

```
struct menu_item {
    char name_menu[20];
    int level_menu;
    bool visible;
    int n_sub_menus;
    struct menu_item *sub_menu;
};

struct menu_item sub_items[] = { {"First sub item", 0, true, 0, NULL},
                                {"Second sub item", 0, true, 0, NULL},
                                {"The third sub item", 0, true, 0, NULL},
                                {"Fourth sub item", 0, true, 0, NULL}
                              };

struct menu_item main_menu[] = { {"First item", 0, true, 0, NULL},
                               {"Second item", 0, true, 0, NULL},
                               {"The third item", 0, true, 4, sub_items},
                               {"Fourth item", 0, true, 0, NULL}
                              };
```

Comment: Вроде как собралось. Спасибо большое!

Comment: А не подскажите ещё как обратиться к вложенному в структуру массиву? (main_menu[0].sub_menus[1].name_menu) не срабатывает. Я понимаю, что там хранится ссылка на массив, а не сам массив, но никак не соображу как до него добраться.

Comment: Так у вас в `main_menu[0]` нет `sub_menu` (вернее, это `NULL`).

Comment: Я ошибся не main_menu[0], а  main_menu[2]. Это не меняет сути вопроса

Comment: `main_menu[2].sub_menu[1].name_menu`.

Comment: А чем это отличается от того что написал я выше? Что то не могу понять.

Comment: Два отличия: правильный индекс, правильное имя поля.

Comment: Прошу прощения, действительно так. Был невнимателен. И спасибо!